# Problem counting screen locking patterns with backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking

The problem is counting the number of paths of length n from a given
vertex in a graph like the used to unlock Android devices.I'm trying to use backtracking to solve it but I don't get right, I'm I'm still learning how to use it. So here is some code I've been trying

```py
G = {
    'a': set('bed'),
    'b': set('cfeda'),
    'c': set('feb'),
    'd': set('abehg'),
    'e': set('bcfihgda'),
    'f': set('ciheb'),
    'g': set('deh'),
    'h': set('efigd'),
    'i': set('fhe')
}

result = 0


def count_patterns(node, length):
    if length == 1:
        return len(G[node])
    global result
    for neighbor in G[node]:
        result += count_patterns(neighbor, length - 1) - 1
    return result
```

I expect the count_patterns('a',2) to return 15 and it does return it; however, for n>2
all the results are wrong by far. I think it must be that I don't actually getting track of the node visited, for example if takes this route for n = 3
a -> b -> c when it backtracks to a -> b it can take a -> b -> a which is wrong so it cannot take the parent of the node as a neighbor, I know the problem but
I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: why is result global?  looks like this works fine if you change `global result` to `result = 0`

Comment: You're right, but even with that I get wrong results but now more accurate than before. For count_patterns('a',4) --> 299 when it should returns me 256. Any idea??

Comment: what's the `- 1` for after the recursive call?

Comment: this is to not count the edge from where came, for example if takes the following path a -> b -> c make counter_patterns('c', 1) would returns the numbers of neighbors of 'c' which are 'b', 'e' and 'f' but 'b' is from where came.

Comment: *"like the used to unlock Android devices."*: that is not a clear specification. On Android you can for instance not connect 1 and 7 without using 4. There are other rules as well. Instead of comparing with this Android system, please specify all the rules the paths must stick to, ... explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the last -1. So,

> result += count_patterns(neighbor, length - 1) **- 1**

Should become

> result += count_patterns(neighbor, length - 1)

The main problem with your code is that if you go, for example, from a->b and then b->a, you count this as a path of length 2. But it's not. A path shouldn't have repeated vertices. There are two ways you can deal with this: (I will only mention the main idea)

1. Have a global visited array that has boolean values (true or false). If you have n nodes, this array should have a capacity as much as the number of nodes. Then, you change your code as follows: (pseudocode)

``

```
def count_patterns(node, length):
    if length == 1:
        return len(G[node])
    global result
    for neighbor in G[node]:
        if neighbor is not visited
             mark neighbor as visited
             result += count_patterns(neighbor, length - 1)
             mark neighbor as unvisited //This is very important
    return result
```

``

The reason that you need to "mark neighbor as unvisited" is because you don't want to repeat a vertex in a specific branch; but you want to be able to use it on another path after you have returned from your recursive call.

2. You can just pass a third argument to your function which is a list of the vertices you've picked so far; then you only pick a new vertex if you it's not in the list. And you update the list as well:

``

```
def count_patterns(node, length, list):
    if length == 1:
        return len(G[node])
    global result
    for neighbor in G[node]:

        if neighbor is not in list

             result += count_patterns(neighbor, length - 1, list.append(neighbor))
    return result
```

``

I personally, prefer the first way because it's gonna be faster and simpler.